# html and css - different height of div-containers

Tags: html, css

In my template I have one big div container an two smaller in it. They have different contents in it, so if I don´t specify the pixel, the containers get conform to the different contents.

I like them to be dynamic, but my wish would be, that the container with less content gets as big as the one with more content.

How can I write this in the stylesheet?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with just html and css, I think you would have to use some Javascript to accomplish this =/ sorry

Comment: Can you provide your current html?

Comment: There are plenty questions and answer for this topic, check them http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+css

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible and there are multiple approaches.  Take a look at this website for a detailed explanation:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks